# SSIS Conditional Split Error - The data type DT_BYTES cannot be used with binary operator "=="

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, conditional-split

While configuring a conditional split component with the following expression:

```
[VersionStamp_Source] == (DT_I8)[VersionStamp_Destination]
```

I am getting the following error:

> The data type DT_BYTES cannot be used with binary operator "==".

*Screenshot:*

[image]

Comment: What is the source for your `VersionStamp_Source` and `VersionStamp_Destination` columns? What is the length of your binary strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the error message, one of the columns used in the conditional split expression has a data type of `DT_BYTES` which cannot be compared using binary operators.

You need to cast this column to another data type. As mentioned in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/cast-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15), `DT_BYTES` can be converted to `DT_I8` or to a string data type.

[image]

As @billinkc mentioned in the comments, casting `DT_BYTES` to a string data type is more preferable since some values cannot be converted to an 8-byte integer.

To solve your problem, try using the following expression:

```
    (DT_WSTR,255)[VersionStamp_Source] == (DT_WSTR,255)[VersionStamp_Destination]
```

**Also, make sure to use an accurate length for the string casting operator. You can increase the string length to `4000`**

Comment: Whether a DT_BYTES can be converted to an integer is entirely dependent upon the length of the binary data. If this is the result of a standard hashing algorithm, even the least good MD2/3/5 will result in a 16byte value which is double what you can store in an 8 byte signed integer. String conversion though makes a lot of sense and one I'd advocate for the user

Comment: Well noted, @billinkc. I edited my answer to mention that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks Hadi ,
Using the   (DT_WSTR,255)[VersionStamp_Source] == (DT_WSTR,255)[VersionStamp_Destination]  fixed the issue.

Comment: @Gidda please **[mark the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)**